# Access to a text node?

Tags: javascript, xml

I want to access to a textnode (Passengers here) but I can't. I'm using javascript and xmlDoc. I have null and undefined as an error

This is the xml file :

```
<FunctionalInstance>
    <ID Value="100177" Type="HumanInstance">
      <Mandatory>
        <ExternalID Type="String">Passenger.1</ExternalID>
        <Relation OwnerReference="100171" Reference="100172"/>
```

this is my function :

```
function CollectID() {
    for(var i = 0; i < acteurs.length; i++) {
     var actorTag =xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("FunctionalInstance")[0].childNodes[i].getElementsByTagName["Mandatory"].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
     alert(actorTag);
    }
}
```

thank you for your help

Comment: What is your question? Please show some code and explain what is wrong.

Comment: I edited my post ^^

Comment: Don't rely on `childNodes` to find element nodes, if you want to find a certain element by name use `getElementsByTagName` or `querySelector` or XPath or the `children` collection. `childNodes` includes text nodes, comment nodes, and in your input the first child node of the `Mandatory` element could be a text node with whitespace and not the `ExternalID` element.

Comment: And `getElementsByTagName["Mandatory"]` should be `getElementsByTagName("Mandatory")`.

Comment: Your acteurs variable is assuming the existence of the child nodes of FunctionalInstance. If the number of acteurs exceeds that of the child nodes length, then you'll hit a problem.